# Why default specifier is not allowed to specify for any class member in Java?

Tags: java

The default access specifier of  any Java class member is "**default**". I mean when no specifier has specified before the member of the class, Java takes it as **default** implicitly. Have you ever tried to put **default** specifier explicitly before a method or variable in a class.  try once and see.

```
Class demo{
default String name; // is this valid???
}
```

I just wanted to know what is the reason behind it?

Comment: _The default access specifier of any Java class member is "default"_ No. The default access modifier is the absence of a modifier. `default` is a keyword used in interfaces since Java 8 and annotations since whenever they were added and `switch` statements since they existed.

Comment: @Pillar "Default access" is the formal term used for "package access" until Java 8.

Comment: @chrylis Cool. Their wording is suggesting it as a keyword.

Comment: @Pillar Correct; the confusion arises because of an unfortunate redefinition of an existing bad term. Nevertheless, until Java 8, the access for an unspecified member was "default" (not `default`).

Answer (score 6):

`default` keyword has nothing to do with access modifiers.

In access modifier's context, it is the absence of a specific access modifier which is called default.

`default` keyword's actual usage is -

1. The default keyword can optionally be used in a switch statement to label a block of statements to be executed if no case matches the specified value; see switch.
2. The default keyword can also be used to declare default values in a Java annotation.
3. From Java 8 onwards, the default keyword is also used to specify that a method in an interface provides the default implementation of an optional method.

Comment: In Java8, default is used as access specifier for any method in interface. It means 'default' is an access specifier from java8 onwards if not before. Now we can say default is an access specifier. Its not valid in java8 classes even. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The "default" keyword is not related to the "default" or "package" visibility (which is what you're referring to). To the best of my knowledge there's no keyword to specify package level access.

"Default" is used in other contexts, such as switch statements, default methods, etc.

So, I believe that your syntax would not be valid, or (in JDK8) have different semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Default is absence of any access modifier. there is no "default" keyword used to indicate a modifier. Hence "default String name;" is not valid.